# Make PowerShell Wait for Excel to Finish Refreshing Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

So I developed a Powershell script to refresh about 40 large excel files and save them, and in this script I run an excel macro to pass the excel (ODBC) connection parameters and then delete them from the excel file after the refresh is done. My only problem is that (for 5 files of these 40 files) when the RefreshAll command is launched, Powershell does not wait for Excel to finish refreshing and passes through to the next command which is the macro that invalidates the connection, which causes the error "1004" in the macro (Cannot access to the excel connection while the file is still refreshing.)

After some research, I know that in Powershell v2, there's the concept of background jobs, but in my case, this is not an aside process, it belongs to the Excel process, so my Powershell shouldn't have to wait for Excel to quit to continue executing, on the contrary, I need the excel to stay open to continue the execution of Powershell.

I know also that the start-sleep command is not the best for my situation since there is no fix value of time for the refresh to end, every file has its time and also every period of the month has its time (the volume of data increases everyday until the month ends).

So my question is: Is it possible to make Powershell test if the Excel file has done refreshing its data, if yes it continues, else it waits even more?

Answer (score 5):

Shotgun approach:

1. Excel has [Application.Ready](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197917.aspx) property. It *should* indicate when
   Excel is ready for automation communication, but [details are
   unclear](http://www.databaseforum.info/16/15/df68562a383083ef.html). Try something like this:

   ```powershell
   $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

   # Do your stuff here

   # Wait for Excel to became ready
   while (!$Excel.Ready)
   {
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   }

    # Do other stuff
   ```
2. QueryTable has [Refreshing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834459.aspx) property. Try this:

   ```powershell
   $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
   $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Path\To\Workbook\Data.xlsx')

   # Are any of the QueryTables refreshing?
   # Don't have Excel right now, so expression below might need some tweaking
   While (($Workbook.Sheets | ForEach-Object {$_.QueryTables | ForEach-Object {if($_.QueryTable.Refreshing){$true}}}))
   {
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   }
   ```
3. ODBCConnection has [Refreshing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820965.aspx) property.Try this:

   ```powershell
   $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
   $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Path\To\Workbook\Data.xlsx')

   # Is ODBCConnection refreshing?
   # Don't have Excel right now, so expression below might need some tweaking
   While ($Workbook.ODBCConnection.Refreshing)
   {
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
   }
   ```
4. Maybe those 5 files have [PivotCache.BackgroundQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835909.aspx), [ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839662.aspx) or [QueryTable.BackgroundQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839478.aspx) property set to true?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well i tried your solution but I still have the vba error 1004.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution. I will test the ODBCConnection.Ready, but i think it has something to do with this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181585/rpc-e-servercall-retrylater-during-powershell-automation since when I take off the part of the macro run, the error described in the post comes up.

Comment: For me #1 just caused Excel to Hang, but number 2 worked when trying to refresh from a CSV

Answer (score 0):

For me this simple code-snippet did the trick:

```
$sheet.Calculate()
$null = $sheet.QueryTables.QueryTable.Refreshing
```

It looks like just getting the Refreshing-Attribute is enough to wait for the end of the refresh/calculation-cycle.