# Wait to refresh external data connections in each sheet in Excel workbook before saving/closing using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I've looked around quite a bit for solutions to this and don't see any PowerShell only solutions. I've seen a few [PowerShell/VBA solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582443/make-powershell-wait-for-excel-to-finish-refreshing-pivot-table) but nothing saying it is not possible to complete solely using PowerShell. I would prefer not to use VBA if possible, PowerShell only.

I have a few workbooks with multiple sheets that are currently manually refreshed to retrieve data from a SQL Server (2008 R2) database instance. I can do everything I need using the following code if I run line by line and wait for refresh operations to complete:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\test.xlsx')
$Excel.Visible = $True
$Workbook.RefreshAll()
$workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
```

The only problem is when I run the whole script, as expected, the `Save()` method executes while the refresh operation is still running resulting in this prompt thus interrupting the `Save()`, `Close()`, and `Quit()` methods:

[image]

I could of course use the `Start-Sleep` cmdlet in a loop to wait for the database connections to complete using a static interval, however, the stored procedures that are executed range from 2 seconds - 3 minutes and seems like a waste of resources to sleep on each refresh like that.

The Stack Overflow answer I linked above lists 3 possible solutions to this but I don't see those properties that are listed available in the PowerShell objects (QueryTable.Refreshing for example doesn't exist using PowerShell). It appears that they're available in VBA, although the code examples are written using PowerShell. Are the examples wrong or am I missing something here?

My question: Is it possible to complete the code above by adding a dynamic 'wait' operation after `RefreshAll()` and before `Save()` using some sort of "Excel is refreshing/busy" property using PowerShell only?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why don't you use something more specific for this kind of task? like vba.

Comment: @Simo Because less code is better to me. If I can complete it all with one language then that's preferred. If it's simply not possible, I understand that and will have to look into alternative options like adding VBA. Just wanting to know if it is possible with PowerShell only.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to handle excel events from powershell. You are really complicating your life insisting on using powershell. Maybe now there is a solution, but this is a very big **MAYBE**. But in the future? Maybe some new feature you have to add will be absolutely impossibile in powershell

Comment: It's like pretend that a car with squared wheels could possibly beat a normal car. Maybe it's possible, but it's very very difficult and expensive

Comment: A bit confused - the examples are all Powershell - but the methods/properties are specific to the Excel application - just like `$Workbook.RefreshAll()` in your existing code.

Comment: @BigBen PowerShell is used to access Excel's COM objects.

Comment: Exactly - so your comment "if I can complete it all with one language" doesn't make sense to me. It sounds more like "Can I determine with native Powershell objects/commands whether the query is refreshing in the background?"

Comment: @BigBen Seems like semantics at this point? PowerShell is the language, accessing COM objects (which isn't a programming language) so it's still 1 language..?

Comment: @BigBen It's starting to seem like you didn't fully read the question. I do see `RefreshAll()` method and am using it without issue. As stated, the whole script works - the issue is with the `Save()` interrupting the refresh operation that occurs from `RefreshAll()`. Correct, I don't see `QueryTable.Refreshing` property which is strange  since I can see the QueryTable object and the linked SO answer referenced the Refreshing property in his PowerShell code. Wasn't sure if I was missing something.

Comment: All back to semantics. My point is that you're *already* using the Excel object model to `RefreshAll`, and just as equally will (probably, not aware of any other method) have to use the Excel object model to determine if the query is still refreshing in the background, as the linked question demonstrates.

Comment: @Simo it is indeed possible. I've posted an answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with the following code additions:

```
$conn = $Workbook.Connections
```

and

```
while($conn | ForEach-Object {if($_.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing){$true}}){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

The `Refreshing` property lives in the `OLEDBConnection` object.

The final code:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\test.xlsx')
$Excel.Visible = $True
$conn = $Workbook.Connections
$Workbook.RefreshAll()
while($conn | ForEach-Object {if($_.OLEDBConnection.Refreshing){$true}}){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
$workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: This didn't solve my overall problem of where the External Data Connections are disabled upon manually opening the Excel document.  However, it did allow me to check whether the Refresh of the Excel document was still occurring (in PowerShell) and allow the refresh to complete.  Doing so, solved my overall problem, where I was finding the data was not present in the Excel document when I opened it manually, and I had to Refresh All from Excel.